# Error in using .NETLink in Mathematica to invoke Matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematica-8, netlink

I used before following code to call *MATLAB* from *MATHEMATICA* without any problem

```
In[1]:= Needs["NETLink`"]
matlab = CreateCOMObject["matlab.application"]
```

But now i have an error like this:

> CreateCOMObject::netexcptn: "A .NET exception occurred: !(TraditionalForm`\"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800401F3): Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3 (CO_E_CLASSSTRING))\\n   at System.RuntimeType.GetTypeFromProgIDImpl(String progID, String server, Boolean throwOnError)\\n   at Wolfram.NETLink.Internal.COM.COMUtilities.createCOMObject(String clsIDOrProgID)\\n   at Wolfram.NETLink.Internal.CallPacketHandler.createCOM(KernelLinkImpl ml)\")."

I installed .net framework 4 on Win 7 x64. Is it a .Net framework error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by reinstalling MATLAB.